# To get specific values in list

Tags: list

I want specific values in list or dictionary
Especially, I want to get title values(ex.orange,apple)

```
data = [{title : 'orange', price : 4}, {title : 'apple', price:3}]
for d in data:
  print(d['title'])
```

I tried above way but failed.
How can I get those specific values

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put speech marks around your keys

```
data = [{'title' : 'orange', 'price' : 4}, {'title' : 'apple', 'price':3}]
for d in data:
  print(d['title'])
```